# AFNetworking and NSBlockOperation crash

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, crashlytics

Running an iPhone app using the latest version of AFNetworking, the most popular crash according to Crashlytics is involving NSBlockOperation. I am unsure whether AFNetworking is responsible or not. The log from Crashlytics:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x2985118298
5com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Crashed
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 9
1    Foundation      -[NSBlockOperation main] + 200
2    Foundation  -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 840
3    Foundation  -[_NSCFURLProtocolBridgeWithTrampoline processEventQ] + 344
4    Foundation  -[_NSCFURLProtocolBridgeWithTrampoline pushEvent:from:] + 298
5    Foundation  -[_NSCFURLProtocolBridge stop] + 88
6    Foundation  _bridger + 64
7    CFNetwork   __block_global_7 + 24
8    CFNetwork   __block_global_8 + 12
9    CFNetwork   ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 18
10   CoreFoundation  CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
11   CFNetwork   RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 74
12   CFNetwork   MultiplexerSource::perform() + 188
13 ...   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
14   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
15   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 646
16   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
17   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18   Foundation  +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
19   Foundation  __NSThread__main__ + 972
20   libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 308
```

Let me know if you need more logs. Can anybody direct me in the direction to avoid this crash? Out of 2500 users 76 users has been affected.

**Update Sept 17:**
Seems like this guy is having the same problem:
[iOS Blocks Async Callbacks Causing Crash after View Controller is deallocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621028/ios-blocks-async-callbacks-causing-crash-after-view-controller-is-deallocated#8203;ios-blocks-async).

Comment: In order to diagnose this properly, we'll need to see the code that is actually trying to pull data off the network. Probably, there's a delegate somewhere (that has been deallocated) that is being invoked on a block - but its basically impossible to tell from that stack trace.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. I have about 50 files which uses AFNetworking to pull data off the network. How do I go from here?

Comment: If I have an implementation file which invokes a block for getting data off the network. Before getting the response, that file (or screen/UIViewController) gets popped off the navigation stack. Could that cause the crash?

Comment: That sounds likely to be the culprit, yes - view controllers popped off the navigation stack can be deallocated, which means if there's a network operation being performed by that controller then bad things could happen. You might want to either cancel the download, or assign the download to happen on a different object.